# OData Controller Get and Post actions for many to many entity

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, odata

Can anyone point me to sample Controller code for Get and Post actions for a many-to-many entity?

I'm using a test project with .Net6 core + EF6 core + Odata8 core.

I've got other entity relations working fine and from what I can see online the examples appear to be for older cold referring to links where now I believe it might be achieved using `$ref`?

I have a company entity which can have many categories. I don't need additional columns in the join table. Just looking for the basic controller examples to help me stitch it together.

```
company entity

namespace Reviews.Entities
{
    public class Company
    {
        [Key]
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        public string? CompanyName { get; set; } = null!;

      <shortened for brevity>

        public Rating? Rating { get; set; }

 
        public ICollection<Category>? Categories { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
categories entity

namespace Reviews.Entities
{
    public class Category
    {
        [Key]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; } = null!;

     <shortened for brevity>        

        public ICollection<Company>? Companies{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
DbContext.cs

    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Company>()
        .HasMany(p => p.Categories)
        .WithMany(p => p.Companies)
        .UsingEntity(j => j.ToTable("CompanyCategories"));
```

Any pointers/samples to push me in the right direction welcome!!

Thanks

Comment: What do you want the controller to do though? If you have a separate controller for the M:N table, then you can execute normal CRUD operations against that using foreign keys or directly if they are exposed in your model.  Or are you asking for how to write an endpoint to GET and post back to the M:N table through the parent controller?

Comment: Where is you controller? Could you please share that snippet? In addition what blocking you are having in your controller? Meanwhile you could [`have a look on this example`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/entity-relations-in-odata-v4#getting-related-entities)

Comment: Thanks both for your thoughts.
From what I have read with EFcore5+ you shouldn't need to define the join table class, and DbSet. What I have above is the extent of the entity model definition. This is a basic skip navigation configuration.

I'm trying to work out the recommended pattern to use - if I can perform the CRUD operations from the parent controller great, or is everyone defining a class and DbSet for the join table because it's "easier"? I don't like the latter approach as I'm writing code that doesn't feel crisp and the right pattern.

Comment: FWIW, The join table is created fine. If I INSERT using SQL I can read the join data (i.e. grab the list of categories a company has) on the Companies Controller okay. Where I'm struggling is Post (haven't looked at update or delete yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trawling of the interwebs and reading, and testing I finally worked it out. Could probably be improved but including my solution here to help others.

The clue is in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/entity-relations-in-odata-v4#creating-a-relationship-between-entities) but there are some issues trying to run this with the latest libraries on .Net core 6 so I kept digging.

The $ref approach appears to be the OData standard way with a few support combinations of the Uri.

```
CompaniesController.cs
<snippet>
        // POST: ~/Companies(1)/Categories(1)/$ref
        [HttpPost("odata/v1/Companies({key})/Categories({relatedkey})/$ref")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateRef(int key, [FromODataUri] int relatedkey)
        {
            var company = await _reviewsDbContext.Companies.Include( p => p.Categories).SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.CompanyId == key);
            if (company == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var category = await _reviewsDbContext.Categories.SingleOrDefaultAsync(c => c.CategoryId == relatedkey);
            if (category == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
                       
            company.Categories.Add(category);
            await _reviewsDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Ok(category);
        }
      // DELETE
        [HttpDelete("odata/v1/Companies({key})/Categories({relatedkey})/$ref")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteRef(int key, [FromODataUri] int relatedkey)
        {
            var company = await _reviewsDbContext.Companies.Include(p => p.Categories).SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.CompanyId == key);
            if (company == null) 
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var category = await _reviewsDbContext.Categories.SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.CategoryId == relatedkey);                 
            if (category == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var currentCategories = company.Categories
                .Where(c => c.CategoryId == relatedkey).ToList();
            
            if (currentCategories == null)
            {
                return Ok(false);
            }

            for(int i=0; i< currentCategories.Count; i++)
            {
                company.Categories.Remove(currentCategories[i]);
            }

            if (await _reviewsDbContext.SaveChangesAsync() > 0)
            {
                return NoContent(); ;
            } else
            {
                return Ok(false);
            }
        }
```